# NDK integration in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, jetbrains-ide

Today I updated my android studio to 1.3 and I enter the NDK (android-ndk-r10e NDK version) path in local.properties (ndk.dir=C:\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\android-ndk-r10e) but I got this error.

```js
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.
Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  
For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  
Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.
```

please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Set `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` in `gradle.properties` to continue using the current NDK integration.

You just have to follow the instruction which is given to you in the error.

Comment: On behalf of @user.clics: There is no file called gradle.properties. Making one and manually adding the text doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I have same problem I migrate the eclipse project to studio, But steel got the same error, Another thing I can't find the gradle.properties file in my project so I added this file manually,But steel can't success. Help me.

Comment: switch to android tab, then in gradle scripts you will find gradle-wrapper.properties there you edit this property. i had a same problem and it worked for me. hope it helps

Comment: Creating gradle.properties file in root folder helped me. Read also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979965/after-updating-android-studio-to-version-1-3-0-i-am-getting-ndk-integration-is

Comment: I added gradle properties and set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" and I get this error. Gradle 'android' project refresh failed
  Error: exception during working with eternal system

Comment: Creating gradle.properties with this flag worked for me (NDK r9d, AS 2.1.2, Gradle 2.10) - I consider this a temporary fix and will try the experimental plugin

Answer (score 4):

Add the following code to your `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
```

This may solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

r10e is fine on CLI with gradlew.

r10e is fine with androidStudio's version of gradle (gradl-2.4 in AS-1.3)

as long as you still use the [approach mention here](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/) by 'ph0b'. see the 'sample .gradle file' and note that IMO and maybe in his view as well - u still dont want the default AS ndk process ( you want to do some extra config work and maintain full control yourself ).Ph0b blogs on ndk show how to do it all yourself and not to rely on the android.mk gen'd by AS. I still use my own exec for ndk and my own make files as explain by ph0b. All good with r10e / AS 1.3 on linux.

my CLI stdout....

```
:app:ndkBuild
make: Entering directory `/home/rob/src/speechnw/app/src/main/jni'
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-ogg <= bitwise.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-ogg <= framing.c
[armeabi-v7a] StaticLibrary  : libaudioboo-ogg.a
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= bitmath.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= bitreader.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= cpu.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= crc.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= fixed.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= float.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= format.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= lpc.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= md5.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= memory.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= metadata_iterators.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= metadata_object.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= ogg_decoder_aspect.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= ogg_encoder_aspect.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= ogg_helper.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= ogg_mapping.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= stream_decoder.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= stream_encoder.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= stream_encoder_framing.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= window.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : audioboo-flac <= bitwriter.c
[armeabi-v7a] StaticLibrary  : libaudioboo-flac.a
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: audioboo-native <= FLACStreamEncoder.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: audioboo-native <= FLACStreamDecoder.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: audioboo-native <= util.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libaudioboo-native.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libaudioboo-native.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libaudioboo-native.so
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-ogg <= bitwise.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-ogg <= framing.c
[x86] StaticLibrary  : libaudioboo-ogg.a
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= bitmath.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= bitreader.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= cpu.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= crc.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= fixed.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= float.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= format.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= lpc.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= md5.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= memory.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= metadata_iterators.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= metadata_object.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= ogg_decoder_aspect.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= ogg_encoder_aspect.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= ogg_helper.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= ogg_mapping.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= stream_decoder.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= stream_encoder.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= stream_encoder_framing.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= window.c
[x86] Compile        : audioboo-flac <= bitwriter.c
[x86] StaticLibrary  : libaudioboo-flac.a
[x86] Compile++      : audioboo-native <= FLACStreamEncoder.cpp
[x86] Compile++      : audioboo-native <= FLACStreamDecoder.cpp
[x86] Compile++      : audioboo-native <= util.cpp
[x86] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[x86] SharedLibrary  : libaudioboo-native.so
[x86] Install        : libaudioboo-native.so => libs/x86/libaudioboo-native.so
make: Leaving directory `/home/rob/src/speechnw/app/src/main/jni'
:app:compileDebugJava
```