# NDK files not syncing with Gradle Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I am doing a project on Beaglebone Black and i have ported Android KitKat on it. Now i need an android app that could help me access those gpios on beaglebone for a project.

So i am using android studio 1.3.1 to create my application for my project and so to access the hardware pins via android i have to use NDK for it. Now when i am trying to sync gradle 2.2.1 with my NDK files it prints an error that i should set android.useDeprecatedNdk=true. Now when i do that it again shows the error that DeprecatedNdk() is not defined. 
Although i have downloaded the latest version of NDK i.e. android-ndk-r10e from android developers website but the error still persists. 
Following is the build.gradle file from the module.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"


 defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.packt.gpio"
       minSdkVersion 19
       targetSdkVersion 19


       ndk {

         moduleName "packtHAL"
      }
}

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
}
```

Also the error that it is showing is:

```
  Error:(14, 0) Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  
  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  
  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.
```

And if i add the property to the file then it shows the following error:

```
   Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'useDeprecatedNdk()'
   Possible causes:The project 'gpio' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
   The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
```

If anyone has any idea as to what should be done regarding this. Please share your ideas.

Thank you

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923519/ndk-integration-in-android-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the new documentation: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview

Here are the latest project setup instructions: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

This just popped up too: http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/

Comment: There is option to add local NDK-path for NDK from File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Structure for Android-Studio, but option seems disable. Any idea why so ?